# Get all the items and limit the number of the img tags only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

What i'm looking for is to limit the number of the thumbnails (img) only and keep the foreach as it is.

Let's say that I have 6 items in the folder, I need to get all the items
but only the first 2 of the image tags.

Is that possible?

Here's my code,

```
@{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("/media");
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath + "/" + Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
}
@foreach (string item in files){

<li data-src="/media/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Name")/@Path.GetFileName(item)" data-sub-html="">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="/media/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Name")/@Path.GetFileName(item)"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
}
```

The final result needed looks like the following:

```
<li data-src="/media/806.png" data-sub-html="">
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="/media/806.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <li data-src="/media/853.png" data-sub-html="">
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="/media/853.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <li data-src="/media/089.png" data-sub-html="">
                        <a href="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <li data-src="/media/931.png" data-sub-html="">
                        <a href="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <li data-src="/media/061.png" data-sub-html="">
                        <a href="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
    <li data-src="/media/735.png" data-sub-html="">
                        <a href="">
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use a for loop with index and then do a if statment to limit display?

such as:

```
@{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("/media");
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath + "/" + Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
}

@for(int i =0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    var item = files[i];
    <li data-src="/media/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Name")/@Path.GetFileName(item)" data-sub-html="">
                    <a href="">
                        // when index is 0 and 1 (first two), render image
                        @if(i <= 1)
                        {
                            <img src="/media/@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Name")/@Path.GetFileName(item)"/>
                        }
                    </a>
                </li>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, maybe i didn't implement it right, I got an error, could you please add the full code to test it out.

Comment: @Pasta I have modified the answer 1. change `files.Count()` to `files.Length` 2. add the whole context. If you still get errors, please modify your question with the error info.

Comment: Thank you, it works with two modifications, added `@` before  `if(i >1)` and changed the `if(i >1)` to `if(i <1)`, please modify your answer to mark it as a solution, thanks again!

Comment: @Pasta you are right, sorry no idea how I got the condition wrong.  But would it not be `if ( i <= 1)` ? since 0 and 1 represent the first two, if only `i < 1` then only index 0 will be matched (which means only the first one will have image)